# How to remove different pages of a website from google indexing?

Tags: index, google

In webmater , i have added only my base url ,but the other pages are indexed. do i have to enter all pages manually to remove each page form google indexing? please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a Robots.txt file to exclude the other pages from being crawled?

You can exclude individual pages or directories or everything:

```
user-agent: *
Disallow: /
Disallow: /products/*
```

[See this answer for more explanation on excluding everything except the root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226432/robots-txt-allow-root-only-disallow-everything-else)

[You can read more about Robots.txt files here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)